# Unable to open XML file in Excel

Tags: python, xml, excel

I've built (I think, I'm new to XML) a suitable XML file from Excel data and my Python program is supposed to port that information back into Excel. But, upon opening, Excel suspects the file is corrupted and if I try to open it it results in a completely white Excel sheet.

sample of the file:

```
<?xml?>
<table name='data'>
<row et_kt=215846 et_nafn= et_kt_maka= et_kt_fjolsk=215846 et_kyn=X et_hjusk_stada=1     et_faeddag=190201 et_danrdag=198612 />
<row et_kt=239287 et_nafn= et_kt_maka= et_kt_fjolsk=239287 et_kyn=X et_hjusk_stada=4 et_faeddag=190401 et_danrdag=199106 />
```

It goes on like that for 100.000 lines or so. It ends with a

```
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Non numeric values like `et_kyn=X` should be quoted like `et_kyn="X"`.

Also `<table name='data'>` data should be enclosed in double quotes `<table name="data">`

Comment: I see, thanks. How do I put the quotation marks around it in Python? I tried using "%s" % str(respectivestring) but that doesn't work.